# Right way to do Inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, rxjs

I was reading the source code of RxJS4 and came across the function which does inheritance (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/internal/util.js):

```
var inherits = Rx.internals.inherits = function (child, parent) {
  function __() { this.constructor = child; }
  __.prototype = parent.prototype;
  child.prototype = new __();
};
```

I spent some time figuring out the prototype chains and think the function does enable us to do 'connect' the child and parent and create a child object with inheritance. But I also noticed if I create a parent object, its constructor, its constructor will be linked to the child function. Am I understand this function incorrectly (that this is a correct way to do inheritance and I'm linking the objects wrong)?

[image]

Comment: Neither of the answer below is **precise**, think the prototype chain as `singly linked list`(when eval `for (let prop in new child())` you're going from leaf to root til null. The diagram you drew above is great, besides all your `constructor` relations are wrong. As the code explicitly says `child.prototype.constructor = child`, `constructor` is just a common prop of its own prototype.

Comment: Yes, I'm not really sure if I'm drawing that constructor link correctly, but I'm sure it's not `child.prototype.constructor`. It says `this.constructor = child`, here `this` refers to the new object created (the pink box). So the constructor link should either be linked from the pink box to the child fn, or from the green box (above pink box) to the child fn. I just can't tell which of these two is correct. @Xlee

Comment: I know what you mean, referring to the keyword of `this` in js(the `owner/invoker/context` of the applied function, obviously in your case, `this` denotes `child.prototype` the new instance created by the constructor.(pink box according to your diagram)

Answer (score 1):

## Objects and Constructors

One thing you have to get used to in javascript is that the constructor is the class. While ES6 did introduce the `class` keyword and the class syntax it is merely a syntax sugar of the underlying mechanism. The architecture was not changed.

A prototype is a property of constructors that the constructor will use to instantiate new objects. So, for example if you want to create lots of "people" you'd write something like this:

```
function Person (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype = {};

Person.prototype.name = "";
Person.prototype.age = null;
Person.prototype.gender = null;
```

Notice a few things. This is basically upside-down compared to other OO languages. In other languages you'd define a class and you can then define a constructor as a special property/method of the class. In javascript you define a constructor and then you define the class (prototype) as a special property of that constructor.

Second, there is not special `constructor` keyword. A constructor is just a regular function. There is nothing really special about it. It only becomes a constructor if you call it using the `new` keyword:

```
var x = Person(); // regular function, x is undefined
var y = new Person(); // constructor, y is an instance of Person
```

So, because there is nothing that can tell a programmer weather a function is a constructor or a regular function javascript programmers have developed a convention where function names always begin with lower-case and constructor names always begin with upper-case. From the code above you see the function named `Person` so you can assume that I intend it to be a constructor.

## Inheritance

Since a prototype is, well... the prototype of an object, then to inherit from a constructor you set the child prototype to an instance of the Parent's prototype. In modern JS you'd do this:

```
function Employee (name, job) {
    this.name = name;
    this.job = job;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // Inherit!

Employee.prototype.job = null;
```

Notice that we inherit from an object (the prototype) because in javascript you inherit from objects, not constructors and not classes.

Second, notice that we inherit by setting our prototype to **a copy** of our parent's prototype. This is because if we merely assign our parent's prototype to our own then when we add new properties to it (like `job` in this example) we don't want to modify our parent's prototype (because then that would not be inheritance).

In the days before the `Object.create` function existed, you'd instead do this:

```
Employee.prototype = new Person();
```

This is still valid today even though `Object.create` is generally preferred. So in the RxJS code when you see this:

```
child.prototype = new __();
```

That's where inheritance happens. Remember, the prototype is what a constructor use as a template to create a new object. So the line above:

```
__.prototype = parent.prototype;
```

Means we now have a function `__` which will create an object similar to the object the parent would have created. So doing `new __()` would create an object similar to calling the parent constructor but without executing any logic defined in the parent constructor. So basically it's doing something similar to `Object.create(parent)`;

The inheritance is merely assigning a copy of the parent's prototype to our own prototype. All the other complicated bits above is merely preparing for copying the parent's prototype.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what I'm asking @slebetman. I'm not asking how to do inheritance or how inheritance works and you're just explaining what MDN already does. Rather, I'm trying to reason why RxJS does inheritance with this function instead of using create(). Because according to my understanding the .constructor of any parent objects is now linked to the child function. It just feels weird.

Comment: @kevlai, and `we inherit by setting our prototype to a copy of our parent's prototype` is technically wrong here, we're not `copy`/`deep copy` anything, we just build the linked data structure, simply saying the prop the parent prototype has is NOT the **own** prop of our prototype, they're accessible from child instances only because they're on the higher level of the hierarchy chain.

Comment: @Xlee I already figured out the child part, I care more about the parent part. Explicitly, how's it gonna be if I do `new parent()`, not `new child()`, because as you can see, I already figured it out as illustrated in the picture.

Comment: If i understood it correctly, the code snippets above is only doing `establishing the inheritance relationship between the child and parent constructor function`, ensuring new Child()[[prototype]] -> child.prototype[[prototype]] -> parent.prototype, new Parent()[[prototype]] -> parent.prototype, that's it.

Comment: @kevlai22: Look carefully again. The `constructor` property of the parent object is not touched at all. When `__` is called as a constructor with the `new` keyword then `this` inside it is a new instance of the prototype. Remember, when doing `new x()` or `object.Create(x)` we're essentially creating another copy of the object.

Comment: @Xlee: But we do and must create a copy. Either via instantiation using `new` or `Object.create`. The prototype chaining mechanism **allows us to implement inheritance** but by itself is not really inheritance. It is merely delegation. The inheritance part is when we can extend the parent object which we can't do without the copy.

Comment: @slebetman using **new** (for e.g, new Foo()), i think we do nothing more than *1. var _foo = {} 2. _foo.__prototype__= Foo.prototype 3. Foo.apply(_foo, arguments.slice(1)), * so I don't quite understand where is the **copy** part, correct me if I were wrong plz.

Comment: @Xlee: The `__prototype__` mechanism is a copy mechanism. Everywhere else in javascript if you do `a.b = c.d` what happens is `b` is merely a pointer to `c`. This is true even for `.prototype`. When you modify `b` you also modify `c`. `__prototype__` is different because if you modify `_foo.something` you do NOT modify `Foo.prototype.something`. Basically `_foo` is a copy of `Foo.prototype`. Note that this works regardless weather `__prototype__` is implemented as actual copy or merely copy-on-write. The end result is undistinguishable to the programmer, only difference is RAM usage.

Comment: @Xlee: Also note that `__prototype__` does not even need to exist in the implementation. If the implementation merely creates a copy of `Foo.prototype` and assign it to the `this` in `foo` then you cannot see any difference in behavior except that `__prototype__` does not exist

Comment: @slebetman If i get you right, you're thinking `_foo.__prototype = Foo.prototype` is the same mechanism as `Object.assign(_foo, Foo.prototype)`, while it is just a pointer/reference that points to the `Foo.prototype` object and just like `link` vs `cp` it uses less memory.

Answer (score 1):

> But I also noticed if I create a parent object, its constructor, its constructor will be linked to the child function.

This is not correct. The prototype chain goes one way, and the parent is not modified in any way.

The only caveat with this implementation is that the parent's constructor does not get called when child's constructor is called. The ES6 class implementation enforces that.

In your diagram there are a couple issues:

1. The instance of `__` does not have a constructor property pointing to `__` function. In fact the very reason `__` exists is to set the constructor property to child constructor.
2. The `__proto__` of child instance will be instance of `__`  (Note the `new __()` in the inherits code) and the `__proto__` of that will be `parent.prototype`.

So, the inherits utility injects a meta-object in the prototype chain, whose only purpose is to ensure that `constructor` property points to correct class in child instance.

It may be educational to contrast this with how babel implements ES6 class semantics:

```
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
        throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subClass,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
    if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}
```

It leverages the fact that [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) takes a second `propertiesObject` argument which can be utilized to add an extra property which in this case happens to be `constructor`. The object returned by `Object.create` serves the same purpose as the `__` instance returned by `new __()` in the RxJS code.